# Sqlite platform does not support alter foreign key ( Symfony, doctrine migration )

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine

I created some simple tables with `manytoone` relationships in them. I tried to generate migrations using doctrine, with this command:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

My database is currently empty, there are no tables in it. Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Sqlite platform does not support alter foreign key, the table must be fully recreated using getAlterTableSQL.
```

I have no idea how to get around this issue, and how to call `getAlterTableSQL` when generating migrations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Doctrine DBAL 2.10.3, consider downgrading to 2.10.2 (the 2.10.3 version doesn't contain security fixes, so it's pretty safe to downgrade) untill https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4257 is fixed.